# Iterate over all array elements and add a variable to element ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, enumerator

I have a CLI App that scraps 5 different deals page and save it into @@all class variable. I want all of them to have a new variable which should start from 1 to 100(because there are total 100 deals). I tried a lot but it just shows number 1 for all the deals.

```
def deals_listing
  all_deals = PopularDeals::NewDeals.all
  @deals = []
  all_deals.collect do |deal_info|
    i = 1
    deal_info.number = i
    @deals << deal_info
    i = i + 1
  end
  @deals
  binding.pry
 end
```

The sample of output that I am getting is..

```
pry(#<PopularDeals::CLI>)> @deals                                                                                                                                       
=> [#<PopularDeals::NewDeals:0x00000001aaf220                                                                                                                               
  @deal_rating="+7",                                                                                                                                                        
  @number=1,                                                                                                                                                                
  @posted="Posted Today",                                                                                                                                                   
  @price="$7.64",                                                                                                                                                           
  @title=                                                                                                                                                                   
   "Back Again at Amazon Campbell's Slow Cooker Sauces, Apple Bourbon Pulled Pork, 13 Ounce (Pack of 6) as low as $7.64 w/ Subscribe and Save S&S w/ Free Shipping",        
  @url=                                                                                                                                                                     
   "https://slickdeals.net/f/10033448-back-again-at-amazon-campbell-s-slow-cooker-sauces-apple-bourbon-pulled-pork-13-ounce-pack-of-6-as-low-as-7-64-w-subscribe-and-save-s-
s-w-free-shipping">,                                                                                                                                                        
 #<PopularDeals::NewDeals:0x00000001a876f8                                                                                                                                  
  @deal_rating="+6",                                                                                                                                                        
  @number=1,                                                                                                                                                                
  @posted="Posted Today",                                                                                                                                                   
  @price="$5.33",                                                                                                                                                           
  @title=                                                                                                                                                                   
   "LUCKLED 20 LED Solar Powered Dragonfly String Lights Multi-color $5.33 AC, FS w/prime @Amazon",                                                                         
  @url=                                                                                                                                                                     
ing-lights-multi-color-5-33-ac-fs-w-prime-amazon">,                                                                                                                         
 #<PopularDeals::NewDeals:0x00000001a84228                                                                                                                                  
  @deal_rating="+6",                                                                                                                                                        
  @number=1,                                                                                                                                                                
  @posted="Posted Today",                                                                                                                                                   
  @price="$339.99",                                                                                                                                                         
  @title=                                                                                                                                                                   
ping @ Walmart",                                                                                                                                                            
  @url=                                                                                                                                                                     
efurbished-339-99-free-shipping-walmart">,                                                                                                                                  
 #<PopularDeals::NewDeals:0x00000001a80ad8                                                                                                                                  
  @deal_rating="+6",                                                                                                                                                        
  @number=1,                                                                                                                                                                
:
```

What I would like to have..

```
pry(#<PopularDeals::CLI>)> @deals                                                                                                                                       
=> [#<PopularDeals::NewDeals:0x00000001aaf220                                                                                                                               
  @deal_rating="+7",                                                                                                                                                        
  @number=1,                                                                                                                                                                
  @posted="Posted Today",                                                                                                                                                   
  @price="$7.64",                                                                                                                                                           
  @title=                                                                                                                                                                   
   "Back Again at Amazon Campbell's Slow Cooker Sauces, Apple Bourbon Pulled Pork, 13 Ounce (Pack of 6) as low as $7.64 w/ Subscribe and Save S&S w/ Free Shipping",        
  @url=                                                                                                                                                                     
   "https://slickdeals.net/f/10033448-back-again-at-amazon-campbell-s-slow-cooker-sauces-apple-bourbon-pulled-pork-13-ounce-pack-of-6-as-low-as-7-64-w-subscribe-and-save-s-
s-w-free-shipping">,                                                                                                                                                        
 #<PopularDeals::NewDeals:0x00000001a876f8                                                                                                                                  
  @deal_rating="+6",                                                                                                                                                        
  @number=2,                                                                                                                                                                
  @posted="Posted Today",                                                                                                                                                   
  @price="$5.33",                                                                                                                                                           
  @title=                                                                                                                                                                   
   "LUCKLED 20 LED Solar Powered Dragonfly String Lights Multi-color $5.33 AC, FS w/prime @Amazon",                                                                         
  @url=                                                                                                                                                                     
ing-lights-multi-color-5-33-ac-fs-w-prime-amazon">,                                                                                                                         
 #<PopularDeals::NewDeals:0x00000001a84228                                                                                                                                  
  @deal_rating="+6",                                                                                                                                                        
  @number=3,                                                                                                                                                                
  @posted="Posted Today",                                                                                                                                                   
  @price="$339.99",                                                                                                                                                         
  @title=                                                                                                                                                                   
ping @ Walmart",                                                                                                                                                            
  @url=                                                                                                                                                                     
efurbished-339-99-free-shipping-walmart">,                                                                                                                                  
 #<PopularDeals::NewDeals:0x00000001a80ad8                                                                                                                                  
  @deal_rating="+6",                                                                                                                                                        
  @number=4,                                                                                                                                                                
:
```

Any suggestions to make it work? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to populate the property of an object with its position within some array:

```
@deals = PopularDeals::NewDeals.all.each_with_index.map do |deal, i|
  deal.number = i
  deal
end
```

That allows you to fetch, iterate, and assign in one pass with a minimal amount of mess. The `each_with_index` method gives you simple index for each element, and `map` allows you to convert that into your final array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this issue is solved. I got an answer. If anyone else is trying to do something like this, this is what I did.

```
def deals
    all_deals = PopularDeals::NewDeals.all
    @deals = []
    all_deals.collect do |deal_info|
      deal_info.number = all_deals.index(deal_info).to_i + 1
      @deals << deal_info
    end
    @deals
  end
```

I used .index method to find index number and added one to it so, it starts from 1, and assigned it to deal_info.number

Comment: This works but keep in mind `index` gets progressively slower the larger your lists get, so this ends up scaling geometrically.